# How to make delete appear in the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my div, there is name and delete. It appears in my web site like :

```
1.jpg delete
```

My html code of div is:

```
 <div id="files1" class="files">
     <b class='dataname' >1.jpg</b>
     <span class='delimg' >delete</span>
 </div>;
```

And the code of `delimg` CSS is:

```
.delimg{
    margin-left:20px; 
    color:#090;
    cursor:pointer
 }
```

I want delete to be hidden at first, so I have `display:none` added in `delimg` CSS :

```
.delimg{
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#090; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    display:none
 }
```

So, when I mouser over the name 1.jpg, delete could be appear; When mouse out the name 1.jpg, delete should be disappear. I tried to use `hover` to realise that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.files').hover(function() {
         $('.delimg').css("display","block");
    });
});
```

But the delete showed had changed with undering the name 1.jpg not behind the name 1.jpg, like:

```
1.jpg
 delete
```

Besides I found that when I take my mouse off the name, the delete still exists. I know `delimg` attribute display has changed to `block`, so the delete is still there. I had tried mouserover and mouserout method. Delete could be appear when mouseover. But I could not clicked delete, because when I moved mouser to delete, delete would be disappear once mouse out the name at once.

Comment: Don't even use JavaScript for hover, there is `:hover` selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use Javascript to accomplish this.  You can do it in CSS directly:

```
.files:hover .delimg{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, the reason that it appears below is because you are using `block` instead on `inline-block`.  Here is a working example:

```css
.delimg {
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#090; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    display:none
}
 
.files:hover .delimg {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="files1" class="files">
     <b class='dataname' >1.jpg</b>
     <span class='delimg' >delete</span>
 </div>
 <div id="files2" class="files">
     <b class='dataname' >2.jpg</b>
     <span class='delimg' >delete</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead if you want to restore the default `display` property of the delete span. and used mouseout to apply `display:none` again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.files').mouseover(function(){
$('.delimg').css("display","unset");
});
 $('.files').mouseout(function(){
    $('.delimg').css("display","none");
});
```

});
Let me know if It solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems as I understand :

1. When the mouse hovers out the delete link does not get hidden.

   In this case the solution is to use the jquery `toggle` method in this line in your code :
   `$('.delimg').css("display","block");`
   So that the add css property `display: block` gets toggled back and gets removed so the link could then hide on mouse over out.
2. Your second problem is the `delete` link gets under the `jpg` in a new line.
   Soltion here is to use `display: inline-block` property instead of `display: block` in you css file and in the event call back method.

However you can do all of this using pure css as the rest of answers implies.

Hope this answers your question.